# What does this line in Makefile mean?

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile

I'm pretty much new to makefile. Want to learn it. Can someone explain what exactly this line in a makefile say?

> `(call makelib_export_shell_noexport_varlist,$(filter gBRD_NEXUS_VARS__%,$(.VARIABLES))) $(call makelib_export_shell_noexport_varlist,$(filter gBRD_DIRECTFB_VARS__%,$(.VARIABLES)))make -C ${b-mk-dir} c-export | grep '^[ \t]*export ' > ${b-mk-dir}/b-flags-environ.sh`

Comment: It means that you have a complicated build system and this is a piece of it without context. It combines two functions, a couple of variables, a reference to a macro, a recursive call to Make, **grep**, and redirection. Which parts do you understand, and which parts do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're missing the initial `$` from your example.  Second, it's not really possible to know exactly what this is doing without seeing more of the makefile.

The `$(call ...)` function invokes a user-defined function.  In this case each call is invoking the user defined function `makelib_export_shell_noexport_varlist`; you'll have to go find that to see exactly what it does.  The function is passed a single argument which consists of all the make variables that match the pattern `gBRD_NEXUS_VARS__%`.  Presumably the function will expand to a string that sets those variables for the shell.

Ditto the next invocation of `$(call ...)`, but for a different set of variables.

Then, the command `make -C ...` is run and the output is piped to grep, and the results written to a file `b-flags-environ.sh`.  Note this is probably incorrect; you virtually never want to invoke `make` directly from within a makefile: you want to run `$(MAKE)`.